# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Decimal]' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

```
var itemlist = (from u in db.getitems
                select u).ToList();

var item= new EstimatesModel
             {
                 id = Convert.ToInt64(estimatelist.id),
                 expiry_date = estimatelist.expiry_date,
                 terms_conditions = estimatelist.terms_conditions,
                 rate = Convert.ToDecimal(itemlist.Select(m =>m.taxrate).ToList())

             };

return View(item);
```

Here in this query note that rate has more than 1 items coming from `getitems` where `rate` is `Decimal` type , so I converted it.

Then I am returning view on single entity `item` where only column `rate` is `List`.

But I am getting this error while debugging-

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Decimal]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

I will use this like this in view page-

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.rate; i++)
{
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">@i</a></li>
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: But what is the type of taxrate in the item?

Comment: @Steve - `Decimal(18,2)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are creating an `IEnumerable<decimal>` with this part of the line that assign the value to rate

```
  itemlist.Select(m =>m.taxrate)
```

Now you materialize the IEnumerable to a `List<decimal>` with

```
  itemlist.Select(m =>m.taxrate).ToList()
```

and pass this list to `Convert.ToDecimal` and, as far as I know, there is no overload of Convert.ToDecimal that accepts a List. Thus the error.

To resolve your problem we need to know what is the type of EstimatesModel.rate

If it is a simple decimal (not a list of decimals) then you need to tell us what value from the whole list should be used.
The first, last, sum, average?

For example

```
rate = itemlist.Max(m =>m.taxrate);
```

or

```
rate = itemlist.First().taxRate;
```

**EDIT** Following your comment below, if you want to store in the `EstimatesModel` class a list of all the rates returned by the call to `db.getitems` then you need to define the field `rate` as a `List<decimal>`

```
public class EstimatesModel
{
    ....
    List<decimal> rate;
}
```

and then you could simply build your list with

```
rate = itemlist.Select(m =>m.taxrate).ToList()
```

no need to `Convert.ToDecimal(... m.taxrate ...)` being `taxrate` already a decimal

Comment: I have rate set to decimal in model also and want to select all rate elements from that list above. I don't get it still with this- `rate = itemlist.Select(m =>Convert.ToDecimal(m.taxrate)).ToList()`

Answer (score 3):

`rate = Convert.ToDecimal(itemlist.Select(m =>m.taxrate).ToList())` is the problem. Is rate a scalar `decimal`, if so, do you want the max/min/avg value? For maximum try:

`rate = Convert.ToDecimal(itemlist.Max(m =>m.taxrate))`

If however to want to convert every item in `itemlist` and return a list, try:

`rate = itemlist.Select(m =>Convert.ToDecimal(m.taxrate)).ToList()`

Assuming rate is a `List<decimal>`

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to convert all items in the list into decimal.

```
rate = itemlist.Select(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x.taxrate)).ToList();
```